# Automapper Mapping Objects of Same Type - Overwrite Bools

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, automapper

I want to use AutoMapper to merge two objects of the same type together, overwriting a field if it null or false. For example, say I have the following model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public bool C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

And set two models as such:

```
var model1 = new TestModel
{
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = true,
    D = false
}

var model1 = new TestModel
{
    A = null,
    B = "b",
    C = false,
    D = true
}
```

I want to merge them so the merged model would look like

```
var mergedModel = new TestModel
{
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = true,
    D = true
}
```

So far, I have the following mapper configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<TestModel, TestModel>()
        .ForAllMembers(options =>
        {
            options.Condition((source, destination, member) => member != null);
        });
});

var mergedModel = Mapper.Map(model1, model2);
```

But, of course, I end up with mergedModel.D = false. What other condition do I need so bools that are false will be overwritten?

Comment: Whilst not answering the question, but from a code readability perspective, using AutoMapper to map two objects to the same target object type whilst at the same time applying some value added business logic isn't going to be easy to grok, whereas a static custom mapping method `TestModel DoMyCustomMerge(TestModel, TestModel)` might be more intuitive? (i.e. hiding business logic away in Automapper might make maintenance tricky?)

Comment: this is some really weird use case for AutoMapper, I would capsulate the logic in the class itself in a Merge method or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're implementing some logic on mapping, better do it on each member explicitly.

But if you really want to do it via AutoMapper magic, you can add this condition:

```
options.Condition((source, destination, member) => (member as bool?) != false);
```